# badblocks and "end_request: I/O error" in output

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk, console, live-usb, badblocks

I have 500GB disk in my toshiba laptop, I tried to do backup of files in this HDD but it failed few times (ubuntu just closed copying operation or unmounted disk during copying files).

So I boot my laptop from ubuntu 12.10 on USB, and I didn't mount that harddrive (it's /dev/sda1) and I run:

```
sudo badblocks -nvs /dev/sda1
```

and output is:

```
[3277.882968] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 825437
```

and milion of similar lines but with different numbers

Should I mount this disk before I run badblocks?
Why it's returning so many I/O errors?
Do you know other applications to check disk? I still can mount this disk and browse files on in, but it looks like I have bad sectors or something is wrong with this HDD, so I'd like to check it.

Comment: Those type of errors point to a physical disk or controller problem. You are on the brink of losing data if you haven't already. Grab a clonezilla liveCD and new disk and clone that thing with the "rescue" option ASAP.

Comment: Any relevant clues from [this post on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176778/12-04-crashes-and-get-i-o-error-dev-sda-sector-xxx-in-console-mode/1047221#1047221)?

Comment: Thank you @XavierStuvw for your answer. I asked that question 5 years ago so I don't remember how did I recover data from that laptop, but probably I used clonezilla. I didn't think about circuits dusting at that time, but thank you for this tip, I'll try it next time with old HDD :)